# How to make Msvc++ express 2010 application compatible to 64bit machines?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, win64

I was browsing the web and found out that my application would
probably not work on (win)64bit machines. And that this is due to the fact
that MSVC uses my default 32bit runtime and sets the application to work only
on 32bit machines.

How can i set my simple application to run on x86 machines? thus making 64bit machines
use WoW64 when executing my app?

I'm using MS visual studio 2010 express (kinda short at the moment).

Comment: NOTE: the application uses two 32bit dll's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

32-bit applications will work on Win64 OS's.

There are some special things you *might* need to do if your application needs to access the 'true' system32 directory or certain registry keys.  However, the vast majority of 32-bit applications don't need to deal with that (some that might include file managers or registry editors). In fact, the redirection was specifically put in place by Microsoft so that the redirections would help the application compatibility.

However, if your application requires a special device driver - that would have to be built for a 64-bit platform (again, this is pretty rare).

You should test your application on a 64-bit platform, but the expectation is that in general it should just work.

Comment: don't i need to set msvc to x86 platform? if so, where?

Comment: Express will only build 32-bit applications, so there's nothing special you need to do to specify a 32-bit platform.

Comment: i'm using libcurl. they have a dll for 32bit and one for 64bit machines. would this be the case?

Comment: You'll use the 32-bit DLL.  Note that there are ways to get Express to build for 64-bit by installing the Windows SDK (which gives you a 64-bit compiler), but I'm not sure exactly how you'd perform the configuration (you might need to use a makefile build configuration). I'd test that the 32-bit build works first, then start looking at getting an SDK-based 64-bit build working.